# How to use PHP htmlentities()?

Tags: php

In my project I currently use `htmlentities()` to filter data coming from the database:

```php
echo htmlentities($variable_name);
```

I am in the USA and this works fine for me. My friend is in Brazil and for him some text characters don't show up correctly.

How can I use `htmlentities()` so it internationalizes properly?

Comment: What Keoki said. Also since you are generally using it a lot it's highly advisable to write a wrapper function -- `html()` and `h()` are common. Using `htmlspecialchars()` would eschew the charset issue and be compliant to the older xhtml syntax. (But better use the charset parameter for reliability).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem could be that the output is not encoded in UTF-8.  According to [the php docs for htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities), the function

> takes an optional third argument
>   charset which defines character set
>   used in conversion. Presently, the
>   ISO-8859-1 character set is used as
>   the default.

So you can try calling

```
htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

instead, and that might fix the problem, since it's not the default character encoding.

Comment: @usnidorg could you please also try simply adding    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> in the head, and not pass additional parameters to htmlentities and check if that works

Answer (score 0):

While I suspect Keoki has it correct, another possible problem could be the font. If using a special character where your friend's font doesn't contain that character, they'll just see the missing character sign. In the webpage or whatever medium you are using to post the character, be sure that a font is set, as there's no guarentees on the default font working.

If neither of these be the case though, what is an example character that isn't showing up? Can you post the full code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try **iconv** to Convert string to requested character encoding

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php